# how to make a update api in laravel using autherntication token

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to make a update API that updates fileds using header auth token

I am new to larvel

this is what I have tried

```
Route::patch('/update', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
  
    $data = $request->validate([
        'name' => '|max:255',
        'phone'=> 'max:255',
        'email' => '|email|unique:users',
          'period'=> 'max:255',
            'babyname'=> 'max:255',
              'baby_date'=> 'max:255',
        
            
      
    ])}) return new \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse(['user' => $user] , 200);
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are familiar with Controller in laravel?

Comment: How do you implement authentication? Using jet?

Comment: i have used larvel passport to create token

Comment: This is a really difficult question because of the amount of work someone has to put into giving you an answer, I'm willing to give you a full solution but you need to provide more data, what is the name of the model you are updating? are you using controllers? what are you trying to do?

Comment: @KGG yes i can give more details I am using controller my model name is users what I am trying to do is to make update form for details of users if want any code let me know so that i can update the question

Comment: Not required, I will just assume that the middleware **auth:api** has no issues right?

Comment: @KGG   middleware auth:api  is woeking in get api

Comment: @KGG i have tryed ur answer pls see the screenshot

Comment: @vivekkn what is the issue/error now?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam as the screenshot there is 200  status responce but the api does not write anything to the database

Comment: @vivekkn you want to update the current user? Right?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam which file should i write this code u gave is it in api.php or controller?

Comment: @vivekkn if you can refactor this code to MVC that's good.

Comment: i added this code in api.php and I got the answer as above screenshot but my db is not changing

Comment: @vivekkn But when you add an api route it has a prefix(specified in app->providers->RouteServiceProviders.php). You need to add /api/ first on the route, like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/update (but remember the route needs to be in routes->api.php, for this to work)

Answer (score 1):

Changes

1. Removed typo. `'name' => '|max:255'` to `'name' => 'max:255'` and `'email' => '|email|unique:users'` to `'email' => 'email|unique:users'`
2. Condition based `unique()` check added `'email|unique:users,email,' . $request->user()->id,`. This will be used to Skip the Current record.
3. `return` should be placed inside the `Route()`, not outside.
4. Used `$user = $request->user();` to update the record.

---

```
Route::patch('/update', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {

    $user = $request->user();

    $data = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'max:255', # remove "|"
        'phone'=> 'max:255',
        'email' => 'email|unique:users,email,' . $request->user()->id,  # remove "|"
        'period'=> 'max:255',
        'babyname'=> 'max:255',
        'baby_date'=> 'max:255',
    ]);

    $user->update($data);

    return new \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse(['user' => $user] , 200);
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

Or for the in-detail update.(Without `update()`)

```
$user = $request->user();

$user->name = $data['name'];
$user->phone = $data['phone'];
$user->email = $data['email'];
$user->period = $data['period'];
$user->babyname = $data['babyname'];
$user->baby_date = $data['baby_date'];

$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Few recommendations:**

1. Use resource route instead of single routes -> https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers
2. Read more about validation rules -> https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#available-validation-rules
3. You can customize the response status:

   ```
   200 Success
   404 Not Found (page or other resource doesn't exist)
   401 Not authorized (not logged in)
   403 Logged in but access to requested area is forbidden
   400 Bad request (something wrong with URL or parameters)
   422 Unprocessable Entity (validation failed)
   500 General server error
   ```

**API Route**

```
//In the api route header
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
 
//The route method
Route::patch('/update/{user}', [UserController::class, 'update'])->middleware('auth:api');
```

**UserController**

```
    /**
     * Update the specified model.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  User $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        //Please read: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#available-validation-rules
        //For more information about validation rules and how they work.
        $data = $request->validate([
                    'name' => '|max:255',
                    'phone'=> 'max:255',
                    'email' => '|email|unique:users',
                    'period'=> 'max:255',
                    'babyname'=> 'max:255',
                    'baby_date'=> 'max:255',
                ]);
                
        $user->update($data);
        
        //You can pass a response status to handle it in your view/javascript as required 
        return response()->json([
            'user' => $user->toArray(),
        ], 200);
    }
```

Please let me know if you require further help or clarifications, always happy to help.

Comment: pls see the screen shot the answer I got

Comment: Please post your router class

Comment: router class i dont undersand is it a file?

Comment: The route class you are using example folder **routes/api.php** I assumed you are using that.

Comment: i am using some,php since there is some issue in APi.php also now I am getting a different error I will post it as screen shot

Comment: 200 is responce but my db does not ubdate

Comment: @vivekkn this is most likely due to your **$request->validate()** You need to adjust that according to your needs, see my recommendation points. Since you arrived successfully at 200 response, this question is technically complete, if you feel so as well, please upvote/mark it as complete, best of luck, dont hesitate to create more questions for future cases.

Comment: but it does not anthing for my API I can only upvote if the API updates the db

Answer (score 0):

Fix your route; it is not found; you have to supply the ID inside the route to reach the controller:

```
Route::patch('/update/{id}', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
// ...
```

Comment: which file should i add this

Comment: Search this in project; probable places are api.php or web.php inside routes directory